# Is there a unique device id in android for a device that is similar to device.uuid in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am looking for a unique id for android device that remains constant on the phone and can be sent to the server with a request made on the device

I have used this method but this generates a different UUID

```
String deviceUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

I am familiar with device.uuid in Cordova, I am looking for a similar solution

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in android as well.
It is unique (tho it might not for a very very little chance in the world).
However you can make sure it is unique by applying device IMEI number , and build number.

Comment: the thing is I have to generate this every time and a different UUID is generated want it to be constant

Comment: You can simply save it in sharedPrefrences and take it later and generate it if it doesn't exist

Comment: can push notifications be sent to the device using uuid